# how to extract and show signature in vf detail page?

Tags: controller, apex-email-service, global-methods, inboundservices

this code is working and view all the data on my vf detail page but i want to extract signature like this is my mail

hello salesforce

**--

Thanks and regards

Vipin Indora

mob no- 1234567890**

i want signature which is represent in bold letter

```
global class ProcessContactApplicantEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.FirstName = email.fromname.substring(0,email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
        contact.LastName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
        contact.Email = envelope.fromAddress;
        contact.from__c = email.subject;
        contact.Signature__c = email.plainTextBody;
        insert contact;

        System.debug('====> Created contact==> '+contact.Id);

        if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
          for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            // attach to the newly created contact record
            attachment.ParentId = contact.Id;
            attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
            attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
            insert attachment;
            system.debug('---> '+attachment.name+' @@@@ '+attachment.body);
          }
    }
       return result;
    }



}
```

Comment: why don't you use split tag to split it and get the signature?

Comment: show the example of split tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `substringAfterLast` in your case. It will solve your problem.

```
string bodystr = email.plainTextBody;
string signature = bodystr.substringAfterLast('--');
contact.Signature__c = signature;
```

Comment: not sure about the requirment

Comment: try regex to find

Comment: `var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

'something102asdfkj1948948'.match( numberPattern )` this will return an array of all number.

Comment: sample string. replace it with your.